# Is the PEB address (0x07FFDA00) a RVA from the base addr of the loaded process?

Tags: c, windows, assembly

I'm trying to work with the `PEB` struct in C/ASM, but before I'd like to understand some basics. 
I read somewhere that most processes have their `PEB` at address `0x07FFDA00`.

Now is this address relative to the process base address, i.e. `(0x00400000 + 0x07FFDA00 == PEB base addr)` ?

Because all processes can't have their `PEB` to this address of course.

Comment: Why not look it up with [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280.aspx) rather than assume?

Comment: Since it's just a virtual address, it could be the same in every process. And it's not an RVA - few things in-memory are RVAs, RVAs are more of an PE thing. `fs:[30]` (32bit) or `gs:[0x60]` (64bit) points directly to the PEB, no offset required. Btw didn't they say 0x7FFDA000? Also, processes don't really have a base address, images do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because all processes can't have their PEB to this address of course.

If `0x07FFDA00` is a virtual address as well as `0x00400000` then all processes can have their `PEB` at this address.

As you can see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808516/pointer-to-baseaddress-through-context-ebx8), `0x07FFDA00` is not a `RVA`, it's only a `VA` relative to the physical address of the process, so `0x00400000 + 0x07FFDA00` doesn't make any sense.

You can check this using `NtQueryInformationProcess` with something like :

```
DWORD pid = GetCurrentProcessId();
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,
                                            ProcessBasicInformation,
                                            &pbi,
                                            sizeof(pbi),
                                            NULL);
PPEB peb_addr = pbi.PebBaseAddress;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, actually, virtual address are just made to make things easier? So every processes have a virtual addr space from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF ? Finally, 7FFDA00-400000 is the a RVA ? Hm i'll dig around physical addr space and VAS. Thanks

Comment: RVA are indeed relative to some VA, but it make only sense in case of the relocation of an image file in a virtual memory space. There's no RVA here. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170843/va-virtual-adress-rva-relative-virtual-address) for more information about VA/RVA.

Comment: Well, a last question please... If each process has it's own virtual addr space, how come if i run several times the same process, the PEB base addr isn't exactly the same ? It may sounds easy for some but i'm still wondering. Thanks again