# ImageBaseAddress in PEB is wrong

Tags: winapi, memory, portable-executable

I'm currently trying to retrieve the Image Base Address of a suspended 32-bits process.

I successfully retrieved the `PEB` VA by using `(*CTX).Ebx - 0x1000` (where CTX is the CONTEXT structure retrieved with `GetThreadContext()`), it's in correlation with the data I got from some process analysis tools.

The problem is that the field `ImageBaseAddress` at offset 0x08 is equal to `0xffffffff`. 
I verified and all the other fields are okay, if for example I create the process in debug mode the `BeingDebugged` byte is set to 1 etc...

And if I look with some tools where the Image of the PE is loaded I see that it's at `0x880000`, unfortunately that data isn't present in the PEB.

So I basically tried to create a *"normal"* process that isn't suspended but I have the same problem.

All the fiels of the PEB are fine, the process too, there's just that 32-bits integer at offset 0x08 that is equal to `0xffffffff` for some mysterious reasons.

(P.S.: I know that the PEB isn't documented and that it is not a great idea to depend of it as it's fields might change in the future but I really need to get the Image Base Address of a suspended process from it's PEB).

Thanks.

Comment: What is `CTX` in this situation?

Comment: you need get *PEB* base address via `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` - `NtQueryInformationProcess(, ProcessBasicInformation)`. but not from `Ebx`. the data in peb of course correct

Comment: Oh excuse me, CTX  is just the context structure retrieved from GetThreadContext (how did I forgot to tell that). I edited the question

Comment: @AleisterCrowley - this is wrong by design way, use context. use `NtQueryInformationProcess(, ProcessBasicInformation)`

Comment: But the question isn't how I got the PEB VA, it's valid, even if I simply dump the PEB structure with some process analysis tools, the field I'm talking about is still "corrupted". And no, you can get the PEB base address of a process at EBX after using GetThreadContext.

Comment: this is bad way (in all sense) get peb address of process. and `ImageBaseAddress` not corrupted in peb. answer - was error in your code. util you not show your code - impossible say more

Comment: If the PEB you are accessing is in another process, you can't just access it directly, you must use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read it. See [pointer to baseAddress through CONTEXT.Ebx+8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808516/)

Comment: ...I actually know that the PEB of another process isn't present in my own address space thanks. I actually use `ReadProcessMemory()` for sure. My program is perfectly working as all the other forensic tools I used to dump the PEB of those processes. The thing is that the field  `ImageBaseAddress` at offset 0x8 is equal to `0xffffffff`. You maybe need some screeshots or others ?

Comment: @AleisterCrowley - ImageBaseAddress  not 0xffffffff in the PEB

Comment: @AleisterCrowley yes, we need screenshots showing what you are seeing, as well as your actual code that  is accessing the PEB

Answer (score 0):

Use NtQueryInformationProcess with the ProcessBasicInformation, the resulting PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION structure will contain the correct peb address.

```cpp
typedef NTSTATUS(__stdcall* tNtQueryInformationProcess)
(
    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
    PVOID ProcessInformation,
    ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
    PULONG ReturnLength
    );

PEB GetPEBExternal(HANDLE hProc)
{
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
    PEB peb = { 0 };

    tNtQueryInformationProcess NtQueryInformationProcess =
        (tNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");

    NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProc, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pbi.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), 0);
    }

    return peb;
}

PEB peb = GetPEBExternal(hProc);

std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << peb.ImageBaseAddress << std::endl;
```

Use the PEB definition from x64dbg [source code](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/blob/development/src/dbg/ntdll/ntdll.h), it's the best source for undocumented structures in my experience.